# HTML/CSS structure for vertically centered text next to image and some elements left and some elements right

Tags: html, css

I have a layout structure I'm trying to build in HTML/CSS.  Essentially it's a top bar to run across a webpage.  On the left, I would like a square image, followed by two or more links that are vertically center aligned with the image.  On the right, I would like two more images that are equal in height to the image on the left.  Essentially, the layout should look like:

[image]

I've made some progress on this.  For example, I have gotten link text vertically center aligned with the left hand image with something like:

```
  <div style="display:table;">
    <span style="display:table-row">
      <img src="icon.png" style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;"></img>
      <span style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;">LINK1</span>
    </span>
  </div>
```

I've found when trying to add the other images to the right though, things start to get messy.  For example, I add the right hand images in more `<span>` elements with `display:table-cell` as the style, but then on top of that there is stretching the table width to 100%, aligning the cells right, sizing the cells to fit their content etcetera.  I basically wonder whether I'm going to down the wrong (or overly verbose) path trying to express this structure in terms of a table.

I'm basically looking for an elegant combination of HTML structural elements and CSS styling that can achieve the layout shown in the above image.

Comment: Check out my answer and get back to me if it is working for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this [Fiddle](http://cssdeck.com/labs/lgtqzxmb)

Key is to use `float`

**HTML**

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="image">Image1</div>
  <div class="image">Image2</div>
  <div class="link">Link1</div>
  <div class="link">Link2</div>
  <div class="image" style="float:right">Image1</div>
  <div class="image" style="float:right">Image2</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.main{
width:800px;
height:500px;
border:1px solid black;
margin-top:20px;
margin-left:20px
}

.image{
  width:13%;
  height:10%;
  border:1px solid red;
  float:left
}

.link{
  width:13%;
  height:10%;
  border:1px solid blue;
  float:left
}
```

Comment: How would one go about vertical center aligning the link text with the image on the left?

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this result without all the absolute values?  For example, assume the entire bar's height should be based off the largest item in it (image or text) and the width should simply be 100%.

Comment: @BryceThomas there are no absolute values in it, I was unable to use % values in cssdeck, that's the only reason why i used 'px' you can try that code in your local machine and use % insted of px, it should work fine